# Why can't the Nodes be linked together?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

EDIT: Is it possible to NOT use `new`? (do not dynamically allocating memory)

I think it is push that is wrong, but I don't know where, how, and why. here is the code:

```
struct Node {
    string fileName;
    Node *link;
};
int size(Node *&flist) {
    int count = 0;
    Node *tempPtr = flist;
    while (tempPtr != 0) {
        count += 1;
        tempPtr->link = (tempPtr->link)->link;
    }
    return count;
}
Node* push(Node *&flist, string name) {
    Node temp;
    Node *tempPtr = &temp;
    temp.fileName = name;
    temp.link = flist;
    cout << tempPtr->fileName << endl;
    cout << (tempPtr->link)->fileName << endl;
    return tempPtr;
}
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
        Node aNode;
    Node *flist = &aNode;
    flist->fileName = "a";
    flist->link = NULL;
    push(flist, "b");
    int s = size(flist);
    cout << "size: " << s << endl;
}
```

the output is

```
b
a
size: 0
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are missing a line or two of code from `main`.

Comment: Specifically, there is no mention of a file "b" nor is there any use of the push() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `size()` function you are modifying the list in the loop. You don't want to modify `tempPtr->link` but rather just change `tempPtr` as you iterate. Changing `tempPtr` won't modify anything permanently. You should also avoid passing `flist` by reference here as there's no need to modify it. So:

```
int size(Node *flist) {
    int count = 0;
    Node *tempPtr = flist;
    while (tempPtr != 0) {
        count += 1;
        tempPtr = tempPtr->link;
    }
    return count;
}
```

As for `push()`, the biggest problem is that you're allocating the new node as a local variable which means it'll be on the stack and will get destroyed when the function returns. To create a node that is more permanent you need to allocate it on the heap using the `new` operator. And again the '&' for `flist` is unnecessary:

```
Node* push(Node *flist, string name) {
    Node *tempPtr = new Node;
    tempPtr->fileName = name;
    tempPtr->link = flist;
    cout << tempPtr->fileName << endl;
    cout << tempPtr->link->fileName << endl;
    return tempPtr;
}
```

Note that the counterpart to `new` is `delete`. Since the new nodes are allocated on the heap they will not be destroyed automatically so you will need to manually `delete` them when you are done with the list. Your goal is to have one `delete` for every `new`, so if you `new` 5 nodes your code should `delete` 5 nodes when it cleans up. If you don't do this your program will run fine but it will have a small memory leak.

(Actually, when it exits all allocated memory is automatically freed. But it's a bad habit to allocate memory and never free it, in general, so you should pretend this automatic cleanup doesn't happen.)

Comment: Shouldn't the size function have the signature `int size(const Node *flist);` because it certainly should not be modifying anything in the list.  And shouldn't Node have a constructor, too...

Comment: Let's not overwhelm him. A constructor is a BIG can of worms...!

Comment: Why is it better to avoid passing flist by reference? What if I need to modify it? Then Node *&flist is crucial?

Comment: @derrdji: The argument should be passed as needed by the function. As a general rule, your functions should be well defined and should exhibit expected behaviour. A function which returns the size of a stack would not be expected to modify the stack; therefore the stack argument should not be passed by reference to that function. On the flip-side, functions like push/pop should modify the stack and will need the stack argument passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your size() function is a little overkill. You might try

```
int size(Node *flist) {
    int count = 0;

    Node *tempPtr = flist;
    while (tempPtr) {
        count += 1;
        tempPtr=tempPtr->link;
    }

    return count;
}
```

I've removed an extraneous exit condition from the while statement that prevented calculation of the length of lists that have only one element.

The reason it's returning 0 in your version is that your while statement:

```
while ((tempPtr != 0) &&(tempPtr ->link != 0)) {
        count += 1;
        tempPtr->link = (tempPtr->link)->link;
    }
```

never executes since your one node has a .link value of null (0). Try the modified version I provided above.

Oh, in the future, you might want to tag these sorts of posts as "homework." You'll get better responses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `new`. Otherwise the variable `temp` is destroyed at the end of the `push` function. Later, if you try to access what that pointer pointed to, it will be GONE.